# Grandpa really likes these brands

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa is a foodie. But he is also kind of picky

> He likes Sara Lee  but not Betty Crocker
>
> He likes Hershey  but not Godiva
>
> He likes Carling  but not Sapporo

I wonder why.

Comment: Grandpa is senile.

Comment: @balazs.com That just made me snort out loud! :)

Comment: As the three different but arguably valid answers below demonstrate, this puzzle might benefit from more examples to reduce the number of possibilities...

Answer (score 7):

> Grandpa doesn't like the letter O.

Answer (score 5):

> Grandpa doesn't like an odd number of loops in letters in brand names.

Answer (score 5):

Grandpa likes brands:

> Named after actual people

The others

> Are named after other things or fictional people